# Verify disown command

Tags: bash, process

I issued the `^z; bg; disown` sequence in order to allow me to close an ssh session in which I am running a super-important long-running process.  This process writes status output to stderr, and it has continued to do so even after being detached (verified with lsof, the stderr fd is open for r/w).

Is there a way to determine that the process has indeed been disowned (will not recv SIGHUP if the shell recvs one)?

Comment: I wonder if this needs to go to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just curious, why not: $PROCESS 1>>/root/std.out 2>>/root/err.out &

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Bash, the `disown` command issued by itself will remove backgrounded (via `bg` or `&`) processes from the active job table, and mark them to not receive a SIGHUP on logout.

You can also pass one or more jobs to disown, like `disown 1 3`. The `disown -h` flag is useful if you want to keep jobs in the table, but still not SIGHUP on logout.

You can view the job table by issuing the `jobs` command. After a successful background, it will show `[1]+ command &`. After disowning a job, it should no longer display in the job table, and no longer be killed on logout. You can still view the process via `ps ux`, `top`, and other process-viewing utilities.

After a job has been disowned, you can wait for it to terminate naturally or send a signal via `kill` to the PID to stop it.

Because Bash is just removing the job from the list of running jobs to terminate and the file handles to your terminal's stdout and stderr are still open, you will continue to receive output from the job until your terminal device is closed (when you log out).

Examples:

```
# we start a command in the background
$ cat /dev/urandom > test &
[1] 18533

# we see our command is still running
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 cat /dev/urandom > test &

# we disown the backgrounded job
$ disown 1

# notice it is no longer in the job table
$ jobs
```

I usually only use `disown` if I run a potentially long-running command like a `rsync` or `cp` and afterwards decide I need to log out without terminating it. If you know you're going to run a command and log out, you can capture the output by piping or `tee`ing it to a file, running it with `nohup`, or running it in `screen` (which allows you to retake ownership of the command/terminate afterwards).

Examples:

```
# capture stdout and stderr to separate logs
cat /dev/urandom >stdout.log 2>stderr.log

# capture stdout and stderr to the same log, and display to stdout as well
cat /dev/urandom 2>&1 | tee output.log

# run a command under nohup (doesn't require a disown or job control support)
nohup cat /dev/urandom </dev/null
```

Comment: +1 Informative and with examples. Nice!

Comment: Very informative comment; are you saying that it is not possible to verify a process's detachment (besides noting that it no longer exists in the jobs table)?

Comment: when you run `detach` on a backgrounded job, it's going to be detached :) there's not really a middle ground there where running it on a backgrounded process will do nothing. checking `jobs` just verifies you didn't try to detach a stopped process or something.

Comment: Is it possible to verify if `disown -h` is already set for a job?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to determine that the process has indeed been disowned (will not recv SIGHUP if the shell recvs one)?

If you have the shell that the command was originally invoked in still open, then you can use `jobs` as @lunixbochs mentioned to verify the process no longer shows.

If you have already closed the shell then you should see that the parent PID (PPID) changes from the parent process to 1 (the init PID). I normally verify this with `ps -elf | grep <command>`

e.g.

```
➜  ~ sleep infinity
^Z
[1]  + 3202480 suspended  sleep infinity

➜  ~ bg
[1]  + 3202480 continued  sleep infinity

➜  ~ ps -elf | grep sleep
0 S user    3202480 1585476  0  80   0 -  1369 ia32_s 18:23 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep infinity

➜  ~ jobs
[1]  + running    sleep infinity

➜  ~ disown %1

➜  ~ jobs
```

now kill the parent shell and look at the `PPID` (notice it is now `1`):

```
➜  ~ ps -elf | grep sleep
0 S user    3202480 1  0  80   0 -  1369 ia32_s 18:23 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep infinity
```

to kill the job run:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```